# Missing artifact org.apache.flink:flink-table:jar:1.10.1

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to add Flink Table dependency in my POM.xml file and the following is the dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This throws the error Missing artifact org.apache.flink:flink-table:jar:1.10.1

My flink version is 1.10.1
I took this dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table/1.10.1)

And I have also looked at the official documents regarding Table API & SQL setup from [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/) which also did't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ you can try File->Invalidate Caches/Restart. Sometimes it happens if downloaded dependencies are corrupted

Comment: I am not using IntelliJ, I am using Eclipse anyway I cleaned (discards all builds) and restarted eclipse which is still resulting the same error.

Comment: @AjayChinni I just added that dependency in my pom.xml file and it's getting downloaded .. firstly i got error repo not found but I tried importing again then it worked.. plus add scope provided too

Comment: @ RAVI SINGH I added <scope>provided</scope> argument as you suggested it still showed the same error but still took a leap of faith and made a jar file and execute it with flink the program worked! Damn Eclipse!!